# Issue with copying to clipboard. Why is my event listener not happy with Tesseract.js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tesseract, clipboard

I put [Tesseract.js](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) on a web server, and it works great.

I tried to add an event listener to grab the content of the `<div id="log">` This is what is being spanned in the, `<div>` right? `<span id="startPre">`

[Here's](http://modulate.byethost6.com/tessjs/index.html) the working version, no copy button
[V2](http://modulate.byethost6.com/tessjs/index2.html) with copy button; doesn't work. I've done this before with a tweet embed to plaintext [tool](http://modulate.byethost6.com/tessjs/tweet2textV3.html), but it was a `<textarea>`. What am I doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div id="log"><span id="startPre"> 
<a id="startLink" href="https://modulate.66ghz.com">Return to Home Page</a></span></div>
                    
<button id="copyTextButton" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Copy Text</button></div>
</div></div></main>

<script src="js/tesseract-ocr.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("copyTextButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var textContainer = document.getElementById("startPre");
        
        if (textContainer) {
            var text = textContainer.textContent;
        
            var tempTextarea = document.createElement("textarea");
            tempTextarea.value = text;
            document.body.appendChild(tempTextarea);
            tempTextarea.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(tempTextarea);
        
            alert("Text copied to clipboard!");
        } else {
            alert("Text container not found!");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Three browsers tested: [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xDWRXjHheicbn5NoNwlxs86_xeq1k5lt/view?usp=sharing) *(Firefox, Chromium, Opera)*

SOLUTION: Simply change `startPre` to `log`.

`var textContainer = document.getElementById("log");`

Which was something I had tried, so I'm not sure.  Anyhow, it works with `log`.

Comment: In what way does it not work? The text copies fine.

Comment: I get an empty clipboard and the error above. (added screenshot)

Comment: Can't reproduce. What browser and version?

Comment: Firefox 115.0 (64-bit) on Fedora 38.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write